# Need help with . string.substring(0, max.Length)

Tags: c#, string, char

ArgumentOutofBounds Exceptions is thrown all the times inside the ifs in the loop.

In this code I am trying to send two strings between the symbol @2@3.

string1+"@2@3"+string2

Now I try to separate the strings from the symbols by the method substring, but an exception is being thrown over there......

```
public void seperatePMChattersNames(string TwoNames)
{
    string nameOne="";
    string nameTwo="";

    Console.WriteLine(TwoNames);
    for (int i = 0; i < TwoNames.Length; i++)
    {
        if (TwoNames[i] == '2' && TwoNames[i-1] == '@')///ArgumentOutofRange Exception
        {
                nameOne = TwoNames.Substring(0, i);
        }
        if (TwoNames[i] == '@' && TwoNames[i+1] == '3')///ArgumentOutofRange Exception
        {           
            nameTwo = TwoNames.Substring(i+1, TwoNames.Length);               
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it thrown and how to prevent it?

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd you have not comment on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i` is zero, `TwoNames[i - 1]` will try to access index -1 of the string - that doesn't exist.

When `i` is `TwoNames.Length - 1`, `TwoNames[i + 1]` will try to access past the end of the string.

Next, when you *have* found "@3", you're using:

```
TwoNames.Substring(i+1, TwoNames.Length)
```

the second parameter of Substring is the *length* of the substring to take, not the final index. If you just want the rest of the string, you can omit the second argument:

```
TwoNames.Substring(i+1)
```

Note that that would include the "3" though - so you probably *really* want i+2 instead of i+1.

Is there any reason you're not using `string.IndexOf(TwoNames, "@2")` etc?

If you just want `nameOne` to be the string before the first "@2" and `nameTwo` to be the string after the last "@3", you can use:

```
int endOfOne = TwoNames.IndexOf("@2");
if (endOfOne != -1)
{
    nameOne = TwoNames.Substring(0, endOfOne);
}
else
{
    // Couldn't find @2... throw exception perhaps?
}

int startOfTwo = TwoNames.LastIndexOf("@3");
if (startOfTwo != -1)
{
    // Allow for the "@3" itself
    nameTwo = TwoNames.Substring(startOfTwo + 2);
}
else
{
    // Couldn't find @3... throw exception perhaps?
}
```

Another option is to use regular expressions, of course - they add a degree of complexity themselves, but they really are aimed at pattern matching. If you find you need to get even more bits and pieces, they could help.

Comment: true, but only if the string starts with '2' or endis with '@', right?

Comment: @jeroenh: Yes, that's true... but it's still a logical failure, IMO.

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, that's what the OP would *really* want (as per my later code), but I was just trying to demonstrate how to avoid the exception in a minimal way at that point. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: i used jons code, seems to work. i really didnt know the syntax of substring, and i didnt know it works that way. thank you!!

Comment: @Dmitry: When in doubt, look at the MSDN documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop starts with i = 0 but in your first if-statement you try access TwoNames[i-1] which tries to access TwoNames[-1]. Clearly this will cause an issue since there is no TwoName[-1].

Your loop should start with i = 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < TwoNames.Length; i++)
```

should be

```
 for (int i = 1; i < TwoNames.Length-1; i++)
```

Comment: @Timwi you are right. as user is not doing any thing with last char. if it doesn't match the condition of second last.

Comment: nameTwo = TwoNames.Substring(i+1, TwoNames.Length); it gives me the same exception on that line

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
public void seperatePMChattersNames(string TwoNames)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(TwoNames);
                int x = TwoNames.IndexOf("@2");
                int y = TwoNames.IndexOf("@3");
                string nameone = TwoNames.Substring(0, x);
                string nametwo = TwoNames.Substring(y+2);
                Console.WriteLine(nameone);
                Console.WriteLine(nametwo);
        }
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet is right the second parameter of Substring is the length of the substring to take, not the final index. If you just want the rest of the string, you can omit the second argument: